# echo data using html

Tags: php, html, echo

i was trying to echo my data using html but unfortunately it's getting an error:

[image]

this is my code :

```
<?php echo form_open("dashboard/edit_product/$product_id");?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="r_name" value="<?php echo($r_name); ?>">
        </div>
    </div>

 <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: Why space between `<? and php` at `<?      php echo($r_name); ?>` and what is the value of `$r_name`??

Comment: im sorry it doesn't have a space. i just had a typo error. the value of r_name is a recipe that is stored in my database

Comment: `print_r($r_name)` and paste its value

Comment: Can you try without the brackets in echo? Like <?php echo $r_name; ?> or if its an array like <?php echo $r_name[0]; ?>

Comment: the code above is my line 68 sir

Comment: nothing works sir @induprakash

Comment: when i try php style it works like this <?php echo form_input($r_name);?>   but i want html style

Comment: type by me sir @chris85

Comment: the div style i actually from bootstrap

Comment: @shikira answer posted..

Comment: what do u mean? @chris85

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From debugging your framework from your comments the answer is that `$r_name` is an array, not a string, as the error suggests. The codeignitor function [form_input](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html) takes parameter one as an array. So you probably want to pull the value from that array:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="r_name" value="<?php echo $r_name['value']; ?>">
```

Depending on how that value is stored this might open you to XSS injections consider sanitizing that data as well. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 0):

`$r_name` is an `array`. You should first `print_r($r_name)` to check keys and values for `array`. Once you know keys, you may further use them to get value. e.g `echo $r_name[0]`

Comment: Use above method and try, I'm sure you'll be able to fix this.

Comment: sir where will I put the print_r($r_name)?

Comment: Put it before form, or any where on page where you could see output. try it.

Comment: a minute sir. i'll try it

Comment: Array ( [name] => r_name [id] => r_name [type] => text [style] => width:300px; [value] => Mango Float )     that is the result sir. i just want the recipe Mango Float to be in my input

Comment: its simple use echo echo $r_name['value'] . lol somebody answered already